# How can I get a Custom Conversion Funnel that records Unique Visitors instead of Visits or Revenue?

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I am trying to get a Custom Conversion Funnel in Omniture that records Unique Visitors instead of Visits or Revenue per event.

So if instances, carts, checkout and purchase events are configured to fire on a particular URL each, what variable should I check to ensure that the visitor is visiting this page for the first time?

Assuming I need to go to Components -> Calculated Metrics. If I check for New Visitor in c12, that would be checking if that visitor was new or not to the whole site and not for that URL isn't it?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you looking for Uniques for each step (page) of the funnel?

Comment: It's been some time but I understood that was not possible.  Yes, I was looking for the unique visitors for each URL